# Free 3D fractal generation

Tags: windows, gratis, 3d, graphic-design

Fractals like Mandelbrot or Julia have always been fascinating to me. I even implemented some of them during my school time. With the power of modern PCs, there are also 3D fractals possible like this:

[image: 3D fractal image]

For playing around, I am looking for

- gratis software
- to render 3D fractals
- on Windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [Mandelbulb](http://mandelbulb.com/2014/mandelbulb-3d-mb3d-fractal-rendering-software/).

- it is free
- is available for Windows and Mac
- renders awesome 3D fractals

I'm not very familiar with it yet, but here's an example created by me:

[image: Mandelbulb]

There are of course better [examples online](http://mandelbulb.com/3d-fractal-art-mandelmorphs/) made by artists who are more familiar with it.

Comment: I remember spending hours just mesmerized in the wonderful world of fractals that mandelbulb generated. Nice piece of software, it is.